# FireFox API install extension

Tags: windows, firefox-addon

How do I install, update, uninstall FireFox extensions on Windows?

The article (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) seems like a legacy information...

I have installed FireFox 3.6.3.
However, I don't see "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions" in my registry:

---

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\3.6.3 (en-GB)]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\3.6.3 (en-GB)\Main]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox\3.6.3 (en-GB)\Uninstall]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 3.6.3]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 3.6.3\bin]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox 3.6.3\extensions]

---

For example, I want to install my_ext.xpi (ID: my_ext@my_site.com, Path: c:\myapp\ff_addons\my_ext.xpi).

Could you talk me how can I install my extension ?

Which firefox's versions support this method ?

Answer (score 2):

The extension registry key (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Mozilla\Firefox\Extensions) doesn't exist by default - simply create it and register your extension there as detailed in Mozilla's instructions (which you linked to).

This method has been working fine for me for over a year now.

You also have another option (which also works on non-Windows machines): [Installing Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_extensions)

Answer (score 1):

The [windows registry method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Adding_Extensions_using_the_Windows_Registry) is not a legacy method, and it's the supported way of installing an add-on for all users on a machine (and all Firefox profiles).

I'm curious as to why you felt it was a legacy method.

Comment: Well, I think you can help me ;) I have updated my question.


And one more question (It is not important for me, but...):
FireFox 3.6.3 has ignored parameter "-install-global-extension".
Will this parameter supported in the future ?

Comment: No, that parameter is no longer supported (this is why the registry method exists).  There have been a few other windows registry installation questions on stack overflow that may help you with your updated question, but I don't know the answer offhand.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about an extension or a plug-in?

Extensions are generally installed by having Firefox open an .xpi file. And .xpi files are just .zip files with a manifest (.rdf) and your various scripts and libraries.  You can install it manually by creating the right directory structure.  On my machine extensions live here: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\[random-number].default\extensions`.  You create a subdirectory there called `yourextension@yourcompany.com` and then unzip the contents of your XPI inside the subdirectory.  The next time the user re-starts firefox, your extension will be installed.  There are a few gotcha's though:

1. Users have to manually restart Firefox.
2. You don't know which profile to use if there is more than one.  The profile is identified by the [random-number] above.  Many users have more than one profile.
3. On Mac and Linux this is a different directory, though the same basic idea applies.

Plugins are things like Flash that run inside a webpage.  You can install those by setting a registry key, but I think in general there is a well-known folder where Firefox looks and loads anything that starts with `NP` (e.g. NPSWF32.dll).  Seriously, it looks for `NP`.  And each plugin must export certain NPAPI functions that Firefox uses to negotiate... stuff.

Comment: I'm talking about extensions.
I know about .xpi and etc...
I wanna have ability to install (update, uninstall) an extension during installation of my Windows application.

Comment: But you really should use the windows registry method if you want it to deployed to all users.

Comment: Yes, and I think it plays nice with the Profiles thing too.